# Adding Joda DateTime to MongoDB -- Can't Serialize

Tags: java, mongodb, jodatime

I am taking a DateTime object and trying to persist it into MongoDB. Is there a way to implement "Serializable" for Joda Time?

Here is the error I am receiving

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: can't serialize class org.joda.time.DateTime
```

I would prefer to keep the format as DateTime, is the more appropriate solution to convert it to a Java Date? I can do that if need be but I'd rather not just to keep the date format consistent.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently only primitive types, Date and classes that extend DBObject are supported through the java driver. You are better of using a mapper framework like [Spring MongoDB](http://www.springsource.org/spring-data/mongodb) if you want to keep your POJO's as is.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and that would work but I think I may make a new question with a wider stretch of what I am trying to do.